# Why is initial J- allowed in Esperanto but not initial Ŭ-?

Tags: pronunciation

Both **ŭ** and **j** are used to make diphthongs in Esperanto: **morgaŭ**, **homoj**, **Eŭropo**, **ejo**. Yet only **j** is allowed in front of syllables: **jam**, **juvelo**. Why is this so?

Comment: One small-as-heck counterexample I can think of is "ŭo" for the name of the letter. But that doesn't really count, I think.

Comment: Because it's so in Polish, German and Russian.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although it is common in linguistic descriptions of Esperanto to treat *j* and *ŭ* in the same way (as glides/part of diphthongs), the phonemic system tells us not to do so, which subsequently resolves the question of initial *ŭ* as a kind of misunderstanding. This goes back to Zamenhof himself, who treated *ŭ* as if it were a consonant (in order to still be able to claim that every sound is pronounced as written and vice versa, although *u* and *ŭ* in fact are the same sound).

*j* is merely a consonant, so it can appear in any position that is allowed phontactically. That fact that *oj* in *homoj* may be a **phonetic** diphthong does not mean that it must be a **phonemic** one - in fact *o* and *j* do represent different morphemes here!

*ŭ* on the other side from a linguistic point of view is a vowel, it's the vowel *u* used as second part of the diphthongs *aŭ* and *eŭ* (perhaps also *oŭ*). The [Fundamento](http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/gramatiko.html) clearly prohibits the use of *ŭ* in other positions (with the exception of the name of the letter, *ŭo*).

The background of this can be found in the Slavic languages, which do not have inherited diphthongs (they all got monophthongised), but have the consonant /j/ and the borrowed diphthongs /au/ and /eu/.

For a treatment of this question in Esperanto see the [paper by S. Pokrovskij](http://lingvakritiko.com/2014/01/21/duonvokaloj-kaj-diftongoj).

Comment: I’m a bit confused by your logic here: 1. Zamenhof treated *ŭ* as a consonant, but actually (=phonetically) it is a glide (=vowel). 2. *j* in *oj* phonetically is a glide, but actually (=phonemically) it is a consonant. – – So, to me it seems that in the context of *ŭ*, you say ”phonetics = reality”, while in the context of *j*, you say ”phonemics” (?) = reality. Wouldn’t it be equally possible that *j* in *oj* (+ *aj*, *ej*, *uj*) is **also** a vowel, and that the same letter being used for a (fricative) consonant in other contexts, such as *jaro*, shows a fallacy in the design of Esperanto?

Comment: A glide is not a vowel, but depending on the linguistic school either a kind of consonant or a mixture of vowel and consonant (semivowel); there is some impreciseness in the terminology. _ŭ_ phonemically and phonetically is a vowel, it's just the metalanguage getting it wrong, while _j_ phonemically is a consonant, which may be realised as a non-syllabifying vowel in certain circumstances. I'll add a link to a linguistic treatment of the topic in Esperanto.

Comment: The terminology is just too confusing. When I was at school I learned that aŭ/aj were falling diphthongs and ŭa/ja were rising diphthongs. Everything was easy and symmetrical. Now I see people calling j/ŭ consonants (sometimes) and nothing makes sense anymore. I just accepted that some linguists use different terms and move on (also, I'm not a linguist)

Comment: `ŭa` isn't a thing... so the information may be wrong :p. Also, the term "approximant" is also used for "semivowel" (IIRC). I don't think a language actually distinguishes between the plain consonant, the glide/diphthong component, and the separated vowel (`aw` v `aŭ` v `au`), thank god, but I may be wrong

Comment: Also, this isn't the point of the OP, but /au/ as a diphthong (aŭ) might get confused with two vowels /a.u/ (au).

Comment: @Zacharý: **ŭa** most definitely is a thing… It’s even ”zamenhofa”: http://vortaro.net/#ŭa

Comment: @CyrilRobertBrosch: I still don’t quite get the ”status difference” between J in *aj* and Ŭ in *aŭ*. To me, they both sound like glides/semivowels/whatever-you-choose-to-call-the-non·syllabic-part-of-a-diphthong. :-) I have a question for you: Does the letter J represent the same sound in the following words? **kaj**, **kajo**, **kajako**, **kajuto**, **kajeto** (malgranda kajo)

Comment: It's onomatopoeia, totally forgot about that. I was just thinking of non-onomatopoeia-ic words (don't know how to phrase)

Comment: If you include onomatopoeia, English can potentially have clicks!

Comment: When I talked about ŭa, I was talking about the sounds in general (I could've said /wa/), not its status in Esperanto. As to why it's a “second-class syllable” in Esperanto, I can only guess (but I might try my best guess as an answer later... maybe)

Comment: @Bjørn As one syllable they may be comparable phonetically, but the phonemical input is different. Word division is a good case: You say _ka-jo_, not *_kaj-o_ (cf. _kra-jo-no_ in the Fundamento), but you say _an-taŭ-a_, not *_an-ta-ŭa_.

Comment: @CyrilRobertBrosch: I would say ”kaj-o”, but I guess that is a wrong pronunciation, then? :-) What if you made the words *kaj* and *aŭ* into nouns, would the correct way to speak them be: *ka-jo* and *aŭ-o*? (Asking out of curiosity, not to split hairs.)

Comment: Extra clarification: *kra-jo-no* because *jo* starts a new (& accented) syllable. I would say *kaj-o* – *kaj’* with *elizio* – just like I would say *kaj-ma-no*. But maybe I’m wrong and don’t accurately hear what I’m actually saying! :-)  (*kaǐ-jo*?)

Comment: The difference between saying _an-taŭ-a_, or _an-ta-ŭa_, _ka-jo_ or _kaj-o_, is indistinguishable when talking at normal speed. The Fundamento has [no rules about syllables](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/skribo_elparolo/elparolo/specialaj_reguloj.html#j-fs1), just recommendations in the _ekzercaro_ section on how to divide words into syllables (see also [_Duonvokaloj_](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/skribo_elparolo/elparolo/bazaj_reguloj.html#i-m1t), last paragraph).

Comment: Nothing in the Fundamento prevents a syllabification like _an-ta-ŭa_. The rule to use _ŭ_ after, and not before a vocal, does not apply to separation into syllables, but to words. And yet you can find [_ŭato_](http://vortaro.net/#%C5%ADato) in the online PIV dictionary as a synonim of _vato_ and without any warning to avoid its usage.

Comment: @Vidamuzo There is no justification not to follow the syllabification rules in the Fundamento. The grammar clearly says that ŭ is the second part of a diphthong, so simple logic tells that both a syllabification _an-ta-ŭa_ and _ŭato_ are wrong. Neither Bertilo nor PIV have any formal authority to change this.

Comment: There are still some things that I don’t understand (like the status difference between the second-last sound in *kajo* and *aŭo*). Still, this answer is the most thorough, so I’ve picked it.

Comment: ⦁ _ŭato_ is wrong because it is a word contradicting the grammar in the Fundamento, but the syllabification _an-ta-ŭa_ is a way to reproduce how the word _antaŭa_ may sound at slow speed; at normal speed the difference between _an-t**a**ŭ-a_ or _an-t**a**-ŭa_ is very subjective and the important thing is that in both cases the accent falls on the last syllable but one. I agree the logical choice is _an-taŭ-a_, but still consider that syllabification falls more in the category of voice expression, similar to the use of _ŭa_ and _kŭaks_ by Zamenhof, therefore not against the Fundamento.

Comment: I don't think it's clear that the Fundamento prohibits this usage of Ŭ. The French version says nothing about it. Also, isn't Esperanto supposed to be a language without exceptions?

Comment: @marcus The other versions do prohibit; there are slight differences between the different language versions, so that all have to be taken into account. Nowhere in the Fundamento it is stated that Esperanto has to be exceptionless, and I don't see why that rule means any exception, it is just an additional rule.

Comment: I guess readers will need to form their own opinion, then. If you say "with the exception of the name of the letter, ŭo", it isn't "just another rule", it's an exception. I am taking all versions into account and the conclusion is that the rule is not clear, you are saying the German and Russian versions are more important than the others. It's been a long time and neither this answer nor the comments explain why ŭ should be a vowel. It's not, it's a semi-vowel. The vowels are a, e, i, o, u. If ŭ were a vowel we could have syllables with just ŭ, which is absurd and doesn't prohibit ŭo anyway.

Comment: No, I don't claim the German or Russian versions to be more important, they just add more detail. The general rule is clear: ŭ appears in aŭ and eŭ, with the letter name ŭo (not the sound ŭ!) being the exception.
BTW, the Akademio has recently confirmed this view: https://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/akademio/index.php?title=Respondoj_de_la_Konsultejo#Pri_la_nomo_kaj_uzo_de_.22.C5.AD.22

Answer (score 4):

In Esperanto, **J** is both the offglide of a diphthong ("ŝa**j**ni") **and** a separate consonant ("**j**es"). If I remember correctly, Zamenhof was at one point considering having **ĭ** as the letter for the offglide letter, and just **j** for the other version.

Oh, and there is definitely at least one circumstance (possibly more, depending on preference/authority/whatever) where "ŭ" **is** in fact word initial: the name of the letter, **ŭ**o. The questionable occurrence that I can remember is "ŭato" for the unit (Watt).

Take a look at something related in English:

- yes = /jɛs/
- shine = /ʃaɪ̯n/

The difference between the two /j/-like sounds in English is similar to the difference between the vowels in "bit" and "beat". Much like Esperanto's `ŭ`, the /ɪ̯/ sound only occurs in diphthongs.

Looking at the comments, it might be possible that initial "j" has two realizations: /j/ and /i̯/.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot! It just bothers me that the letter J is used for two different sounds, but I guess that is unavoidable. (Just like N sometimes can be heard with the pronunciation /ŋ/, as in *lingvo*).

Comment: They sort-of do. but they're not really distinct either

Comment: Clarification: J is used for the same sound (I can't recall if an offglide and the corresponding semivowel are equivalent or not, so take what I say with a grain of salt). English offglide v. semivowel are definitely distinct sounds (in theory at least).

Comment: Jes is a dipthong as well.

Comment: Can you provide a reference? In every transcription of Esperanto I've seen its /jes/ not /i̯es/.

Comment: To this day, I'm still puzzled by the difference that's supposed to exist between [j] and [ɪ̯].

Comment: Same difference between b**i**t and b**y**te, except a LOT harder to hear.

Comment: I think Karlomanio is trying to say "je" in "jes" is a rising diphthong and "ej" is a falling diphthong. I don't think calling j a consonant when it's before the vowel and calling j a semivowel when it's after it helps in making the concepts clearer.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it's just the combination of a couple of things:

- Zamenhof didn't create any “full” word with Ŭ in that position and seemed to avoid it (substituting V in most cases, except in the name of the letter and onomatopoeia, where the sound is really important and couldn't be changed to V).
- The Eastern European languages that inspired him usually worked the same way, being biased towards V.
- Zamenhof created the H-method where U and Ŭ look the same, so it seems that all the uses of Ŭ are supposed to be obvious (aŭ, eŭ). That wouldn't work if Ŭ was meant to appear anywhere in a word.
- Some people consider the name of the letter to be somewhat *second class*. I don't understand this at all (it's OK to say that onomatopoeia may break some language rules, but not letter names).
- There are some versions of the Fundamento that explicitly say that Ŭ should be used only after vowels and for whatever reason these versions are regarded higher (probably because it's their mother tongue, see next point). Unfortunately, they seem to be the versions I can't read (Russian and German only), so I can't check *if they mandate this rule or just note the fact that other combinations don't happen*. Notice that some sections of the Fundamento have some inconsistencies and can't be taken literally, you have to take them all into account. For example, the Russian version (I'm using Google Translate) seems to have several allowances for Russian beginners, such as pronouncing H and Ĥ the same and omitting the definite article, but these are not considered valid rules of the language nowadays (if they ever were). The English version says that “e” sounds like “a” in “make” (which would be “ej” in many accents) and that doesn't make the sounds “e” and “ej” equivalent in Esperanto, it was just a simplification for English speakers.
- People see the world with their own biases, so a French or Brazilian or English guy wouldn't blink at ŭato, while a Russian or German would think “this sounds odd, it looks out of place”. Geraldo Mattos, ex-president of the Akademio de Esperanto, states that Ŭ is just like any other letter (as his personal opinion): http://host.uniroma3.it/laboratori/laat/konferencoj/2006-miljorini/Mattos-prel-eo.doc (6th page) (*)

In summary I think that syllable-initial Ŭ is not really disallowed (as proven by the letter name), it's just an uncommon sound combination, just like “bv” in Zimbabvo or “pf” in Pfenigo, and people are not very keen of changing its status in fear of making a mess of the language's phonotactics. But if a combination as uncommon as Pfenigo (a monetary unit) is allowed, then Ŭono (another monetary unit) should be allowed too, at least as a partially adapted word, because it is unavoidable when talking about the monetary unit.

**Addendum**: The Akademio in its recommendation about proper names
(http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/oficialaj_informoj/oficialaj_informoj_22_2013.html) does not disallow the “Rŭando” because it's against some specific rule, but because it is “nekutima” (uncommon) and could be pronounced just like “Ruando” by many speakers (Ruando being the *preferred* form). The academy seems to be much more careful about mandating/prohibiting anything than most internet denizens.

(*)

> [...] Multaj ne facile prononcas la konsonantajn grupojn kv kaj gv kaj tial
> transformas ilin respektive en kǔ kaj gǔ, sed tio estas prononco, ne
> skribo. La oficiala formo de la citita landnomo estas Gvatemalo.
>
> La plej konataj vortaroj ordinare listas nur tri vortojn sub la supra
> litero: ǔa, ǔato, ǔo. Cherpillod (1988, p. 169) registras dek unu,
> inter ili la vorton  ǔono.
>
> Al la unua demando mia respondo estas
> klara: ne, tute ne! La konsonanto ǔo estas egala al ĉiu alia, kaj
> povas esti uzata antaǔ kaj post vokalo. Jen miaj argumentoj:
>
> 1. La Franca Gramatiko bezonis nur klarigon pri la dekreskaj diftongoj, kiujn ĝi ne konas, kaj tiu klarigo aperas per germana
>    vorto, dum la Pola bezonis nenian, ĉar ekzistas litero por tiu sono:
>    la trastrekita lo.
> 2. Estas multaj vortoj, kiuj finiĝas per tiu glitanto, sed en la Fundamento estas unu vorto, kiu komenciĝas per ĝi: ĝia nomo. Se la
>    Fundamento mem ĝin uzas antaǔ vokalo, tia pozicio estas Fundamenta.
> 3. La Ekzercaro prezentas en 2:16 la vorton majo, kiun ni devas legi ma.jo, kaj ne maj.o. El tio mi konkludas, ke la vortojn  kontraǔa,
>    kontraǔe, kontraǔi, kontraǔro kaj kontraǔu ni devas legi kon.tra.ǔa,
>    kon.tra.ǔe, kon.tra.ǔi, kon.tra.ǔo kaj kon.tra.ǔu... Se tiuj du
>    glitantoj komencas silabon, kohere ili rajtas komenci ankaǔ vorton!
> 4. La Germana kaj la Rusa Gramatiko informas, ke tiu sono aperas post vokalo, sed la Angla, ke tiu sono formas diftongojn, kaj tio en lingvo
>    kun multaj diftongoj: wait [ǔejt].. Diftongon tamen povas estigi ĉiu
>    el tiuj du konsonantoj: dekreskan en la vortoj aj kaj aǔ kaj kreskan
>    en la vortoj ja kaj ǔa. La angla instruo ampleksas la germanan.
> 5. Se la Fundamento mem sin kontraǔdiras, kaj tio restas supre pruvita, ni estas tute liberaj...  Mi mem ne dubas, ke nia tradicio
>    jam akceptis la vortojn kun kreska diftongo en ĝia komenco.
> 6. Se tiu posta diftongiga sono vere estus barata de la Fundamento, Zamenhof ne proponus vorton, kiu komenciĝas per ĝi: ǔa...
>
> La respondo al la dua kaj tria demandoj dependas de la rilato inter
> iliaj kondiĉoj: 1. Se unu el ili enhavas la alian, mi respondas:
> permesata kaj deviga. 2. Se unu el ili ne enhavas la alian, temas pri
> konflikto, kaj ni devas turni nin al la Ekzercaro, eventuale al
> analogio: ĉiu elektas unu el tiuj eblecoj laǔ sia tuta bontrovo.
>
> Se ni
> analizas nun la suprajn kondiĉojn por decidi pri la uzo de la glitanto
> ǔo, ni konstatas, ke tri el la kvin lingvoj vidas en ĝi konsonanton
> egalan al ĉiuj aliaj, sed du el ili ĝin restriktas al postvokala uzo:
> temas pri konflikto, kiun tamen la Ekzercaro de la Fundamento (1963,
> p. 81) solvas per kontrauzekzemplo en la fino de la unua paragrafo.
>
> *Geraldo Mattos, ex-president of the Akademio de Esperanto*

Comment: National-language bias in our perception of Esperanto. :-) This is very interesting. I really like the phrase: *Se la Fundamento mem ĝin uzas antaǔ vokalo, tia pozicio estas Fundamenta.* But I guess others would disagree?

Comment: As I usually say: if Zamenhof were really serious about prohibiting ŭ in front of syllables, he could have proposed aŭ or eŭ (or iŭ, or oŭ...) as the name of the letter!

Comment: The German version of the Fundamento at http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/gramatiko_germana.html says "u ― wie das kurze u in glauben (wird nur nach einem Vokal gebraucht)". This is presumably meant to be a ǔ. I would translate the parenthetical as "(only used after a vowel)" -- i.e. it seems to be descriptive rather than prescriptive.

Answer (score 2):

**ŭ** in fact is a "clever" solution for phoneticising (one letter - one sound) of **au** and **eu** in national languages (**av** and **ev** would have looked bad in non-Cyrillic script). Because Esperanto intends to avoid spelling ambiguities, an independent usage of **ŭ** is rare. With the exception of **ŭato** for Watt, Volt-Ampere and for some English names like maybe Isle of Wight.

For the same reason there is no suffix **-ij** but **-uj** (for country names): the spelling would be too ambiguous, as many national language speakers would tend to (erroneously) pronounce *io* anyway as *ijo*.

The short answer would be: there already is the `v` for normal, full length usage of the w sound.

Comment: [v] and [w] are different sounds, the former is not a longer version of the latter.

Comment: @marcus The Esperanto **v** is more or less a w sound. Hence **vorto** = word, Or do you  mean the exact phonetic definition in Esperanto of **v**?

Comment: @JoopEggen Indeed, ⟨v⟩ in Esperanto varies between [v] and [ʋ], the latter of which is the standard Dutch pronunciation for ⟨w⟩, while the former is the one for Dutch ⟨v⟩. So it indeed makes sense that ⟨v⟩ functions (at least partially) as a w-sound. I suppose [v] is kind of a longer and stronger version of [ʋ], but I am not sure how phonetically sound that is. At least the former is a fricative, while the latter an approximant.

Comment: If I remember correctly, "kiuj" has "-uj".

Comment: @Zacharý I meant that Zamenhof did introduce the ending **-ujo** for country like _Svedujo, Svisujo, Francujo_ instead of a bit more international **-ijo**, because **ij** would cause spelling ambiguities,

Comment: He [Zamenhof] didn't entirely avoid the problem. As seen in a different question (regarding double letters, I think): prefixes and suffixes can muddy the waters when it comes to Esperanto phonology/phonotactics: pr**ij**uĝi (https://www.esperanto-panorama.net/vortaro/eoen.htm) does have "ij". But I suppose a few prefix collisions aren't as bad as about half of the countries getting ambiguities.

Comment: Also, is giving the decomposition of the unit really necessary? A watt **is** a volt ampère in terms of units.

Comment: @Zacharý you are right about the unit Watt is; but Watt was already mentioned as SI unit, so I wanted to vary a bit, and VA is quite common.

Comment: **V** vs **Ŭ**: what bothers me most is the inconsistency. You’ve got **jam – maj’**, **varm’ – av’** but only **aŭ**. In other words: Both J and V can appear before and after a vowel in Esperanto, but Ŭ can only appear after a vowel. :-/ (That said, I have no problems with V as a [w] transliteration – e.g. Washington > Vaŝingtono.)

Comment: @Bjørn one probably has to admit, it is a mechanism to have something like `au`, `eu` in the language; a form of synaeresis / diphthong.

Comment: @JoopEggen, you are probably right. :-) The alternative would be to write diphthongs with ordinary vowels – **baldau**, **homoi** – and use some kind of marker to show when the two vowels should be distinct syllables (hiatus): **bala-u/balaü/bala’u tui la straton! au ĉu vi volas unue luï balaïlon?**

Comment: Also, had Zamenhof decided on *w* instead of *ŭ* (*baldaw*, *Ewropo*), it would probably have opened the door for lots of imports like *wato*, *wajfajo* (for WiFi) and what not!

Comment: The inconsistency bothers me too. I'm okay with letters that are rarer in certain situations, but I'm bothered when people say that ŭa, ŭo are *unpronounceable” (c'mon) or *wrong* (reading too much into the Fundamento) and sometimes even suggest a new name for the letter...

Comment: @JoopEggen I meant that it doesn't matter how long you pronounce [w] (ŭ), it won't change into [v] unless you articulate it differently intentionally. It's just a different sound, just like j and ĵ.

Comment: @marcus understood; agreed